# Swift - app deployment to iTune, while download have logical statement per url?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store-connect, itunes-store

How to deploy app in iTune in a way, when user download the app, app retrieve value from `RESELLERID`, and based on `RESELLERID` it deploy the app which will communicate to one subdomain

**for example:**

***a)*** By default the app URL is:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kindle-read-ebooks-magazines/id302584613?mt=8

when a user install this app with this url, he use our main default services

***b)*** but if it is RESELLER then url is as below:

"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kindle-read-ebooks-magazines/id302584613?mt=8" + **"&RESELLERID=reseller5"**

when user use this url then his app uses the reseller subdomain to our server.

**for example:**

i have 5 reseller and later it will be 50 or growing to unlimited, each reseller have there own subdomain with my server such as:

`https://main.boss.example.com
https://reseller1.example.com
https://reseller2.example.com
https://reseller3.example.com
https://reseller4.example.com
https://reseller5.example.com
https://reserllerXYZ.example.com`

So, when a client of `reseller4 or X` have to install iOS app, that app has to connect to `reseller5 or X` subdomain not to the default subdomain `main.boss`

I cant find anything similar while researching, does anyone have any idea, how you do that?

**End user experience remain simple:**

1 - User land in iTune

2 - Download and install the app

3 - when app is launched, user do not submit (NO username/password, NO mobile input, NP email input none) only view data from specific `reseller accounts`.

if no RESELLERID value was found then the app get installed for main.boss

if RESELLERID value was found, then the app redirects to the correct reseller subdomain

Comment: have you tried this method ? application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: in app delegate to capture URL. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: @YumYumYum Were you able to find the solution of your problem? I am facing the similar. Please do suggestions.

Comment: NO - unfortunately i was not able to crack it. And iOS community do not understand exactly my question i tried many places many forums and i was absolutely ignored / trashed. Finally unable to solve that. Please make more new question, new requests and link to the same so that you have same problem members together to shout.